# Fixing range hood wiring inside cabinet

Tags: electrical, wiring, code-compliance

We just moved in to a new house and the inspector noted that the wiring above the range hood was done improperly:

[image: Wiring above range hood, indicating spliced connection]

There appears to be a splice in the cable without a junction box so the inspector recommended we put that all inside a junction box.

I just have a few questions:

1. Does the box need to be metal or can I use one of the plastic ones?
2. If it does need to be metal, does it need to be grounded?
3. If it does need to be grounded, can I wire it to the ground screw on the receptacle? Or can I wire the box to the ground that comes from the appliance cables themselves?
4. Does the box need to be "attached" to the wall or cabinet, or can it just be sitting loose?

Or is it not possible to fix this to code without removing the whole range hood? I'd like to avoid this if possible.

Located in Ontario, Canada if it matters.

Comment: Unplug it and take the tape off. Doesn't look like enough wire to do anything except take it down, open it up, cord it, and put it back. Also, maybe there's enough space to shove the splice inside the thing. If not, somebody screwed you on wire length, like it got demoed somewhere, had it's cord cut, and then shoved into your house.

Comment: You're right; I took the tape off and they only left about an inch of hot and neutral coming out of the unit. It barely protrudes into the cabinet. I'll have to take the whole thing down like you suggested. Sigh. Thanks!